# How to set a specific initial size for items in a react-grid-layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using `react-grid-layout` to create a dashboard with resizable and draggable cards. Each card is a `ResponsiveGridLayout` item and takes up the size of a single grid unit. I want the cards to have a specific size when the site loads.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo} from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from 'react-grid-layout';
import _ from 'lodash';

import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';

const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);

const renderCard = (key, header, body) => (
  <div key={key}>
    <Card bg="dark" text="white"  style={{ height: '100%' }}>
      <Card.Header>{header}</Card.Header>
      <Card.Body onMouseDown={(event) => {
        // Stop propagation to prevent drag from starting
        event.stopPropagation();
      }}>
        {body}
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  </div>
);

function Dashboard() {


  const cards = useMemo(() => [
    { id: "1", header: 'Hello There', body: <Card.Text>XXX</Card.Text> },
    { id: "2", header: 'General Kenobi', body: <Card.Text>What.up</Card.Text> },
  ], []);

  function generateLayout() {
    return _.map(cards, function(card, i) {
      const y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      return {
        x: (i * 2) % 12,
        y: Math.floor(i / 6) * y,
        w: 100,
        h: y,
        i: card.id,
      };
    });
  }



  const [layout] = useState(() => {
    const savedLayout = localStorage.getItem('layout');
    return savedLayout ? JSON.parse(savedLayout) : generateLayout();
  });



  const colWidth = 1;
  const rowHeight = 1;
  const calculateCols = () => Math.floor(window.innerWidth / colWidth);

  return (
    <div>
        <ResponsiveGridLayout
          className="layout" 
          layout={layout} 
          isResizable={true}
          cols={{lg: calculateCols(), md: calculateCols(), sm: calculateCols()}}
          rowHeight={rowHeight}
          compactType={null}
          verticalCompact={false}
        >
          {cards.map(card => renderCard(card.id, card.header, card.body))}
        </ResponsiveGridLayout>
    </div>
    
  );
  
}


export default Dashboard;
```

I want the cards to have a specific size or even better depending on number of items visible and window size.
How can I set a specific initial size for the cards in my `react-grid-layout`?
I mean there has to be a function for the resizing of the grid-item which should be callable??